# What ends up happening when we try to use regex modifiers in awk?

Tags: awk

See this output:

```
❯ awk '/indubitably/i' /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l 
102401
```

`Awk` does not complain about invalid syntax or anything like that, and just spits out all lines in the file (`words` indeed has 102401 words inside).

Since it's very reasonable as an awk newbie to try this as a guess for case insensitivity (I am aware that `IGNORECASE=1;` is the right way to do it) I'm now curious how awk actually interprets `/indubitably/i`.

Comment: It concatenates the value of `/indubitably/` which is 1 if a match and 0 if not converted to a string, with the value of the variable `i` which wasn't set to anything and thus is an empty string, and tests if the result is nonempty which it always is, hence on every line the default action of `{print $0}` is executed.

Comment: That "no operator" string concatenation is sometimes a loaded gun.

Comment: What version of `awk` are you using (what is output of `awk --version`)?

Comment: `IGNORECASE` is gawk-only, portably you'd do `tolower($0) ~ /indubitably/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually there's nothing invalid about that syntax.

it's regex matching "`indubitably`" anywhere in each input line, and concat with a uninitialized variable "`i`" that, by default, is an empty string, or boolean value of False.

but i'm guessing what happened instead, is that `awk` concatenating that empty string into regex (not as a comparison item, but afterwards), which becomes a non-empty string, since you have a word inside the regex.

and basically anything that evaluates to `non-zero numerically or non-empty string becomes a boolean True at the pattern level`, which then defaults to print as an action. you literally can throw anything there -

writing a "`1`" there is just conventional notation, but you can even place `NF`, `OFMT`, `FNR`, `SUBSEP`, or `RS` right there at the pattern (as long as it's not an empty string), and it'll work as if you've placed a "`1`" there.